# What is the difference between Laravel app->make(ClassA) class and new ClassA()

Tags: php, laravel, oop

I need to know what is the difference between the following approaches, and what are the main objectives or characteristics of each method?

It would be great if anyone can teach me about this or give me a good reference to follow.

```
$class = app()->make(ClassA::class);
```

vs

```
$class = new ClassA();
```

Answer (score 11):

This is a big question and I don't think it is easily explainable in a StackOverflow answer.

But in a summary, the first approach uses a so called Dependency Injection technique. In Laravel the [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/master/container) is the one that resolves the dependencies around the framework. 
So for example if your class is dependent on other resources being available at the runtime, the Service Container will take care of providing those.

And the latter is just a plain object instantiation that you do it yourself.

For example your `ClassA` in the constructor has a dependency to another class:

```
public function __construct(ClassB $classB) {}
```

Then using the first approach the Service container will try to resolve the ClassB for you, and using the second approach you are the one that needs to provide that dependency like this:

```
$class = new ClassA(new ClassB);
```

I hope that this clarifies it a bit even though as I mentioned it is a big question.

Comment: so both of these approaches are doing the same job though. Correct me if I am wrong. as an example, if I want to call methodA() which belongs to ClassA, I can do 
$class = app()->make(ClassA::class); $class->methodA()  and $class = new ClassA(); $class->methodA(). right?

Comment: bottom line yes. But then again, there is a lot going on, we cannot discuss a software architecture in a single thread :)

Comment: if you want to use it for your example above I suggest you use the second approach and that's it.

Comment: Perfect Mate. Can you please share if you have some references. your answer was really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: You can go through the docs, the link that I gave you above click on the Service Provider to read more. Also Laravel Up & running book is a great resource to have. It is by Matt Stauffer